# Async call to API from WPF in machine having OS Windows 7

Tags: wpf, api, windows-7

I'm unable to make async call from wpf application (exe) developed in .Net 4.7.2 and calling Web API developed in .Net Core 3.1 in the machine having OS Windows 7.

Kindly help if anybody is aware about the issue like this.

Comment: Is this an existing application or one you are developing? Do you also develop/maintain the API you are attempting to consume? Please share details about your project including relevant code samples and the complete error you are receiving. Please see the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article for more information.

Comment: It was an existing application working fine with WCF service. We have just implemented API as an alternative of WCF. Yes API is developed by myself. 

Working Scenario:
I'm simply making getasync call from one of the method. It works fine when we use "await" keyword while calling the async method in Windows 7 and Windows 10 both.

Error Scenario:
Instead of using "await" keyword, when I use ".Result", execution get stuck when it's Windows 7 whereas it works fine in Windows 10.